# UICollectionView not the right size in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I have a simple UICollectionView defined in my storyboard (see screenshot).

[image]

I'm using auto layout, the UICollectionView is attached to the superview for leading, trailing and top and to the toolbar for the bottom.

When I display in the console the size of the UICollectionView in viewDidLoad with:

```
NSLog(@"%s CollectionView ========== > height:%f width:%f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,self.theCollectionView.bounds.size.height, self.theCollectionView.bounds.size.width);
```

I get:
CollectionView ========== > Frame height:492.000000 width:600.000000

This size is the one which is also displayed in the storyboard (Width:600 Height:492).

When I run the same log in viewDidAppear, I get:
CollectionView ========== > Frame height:663.000000 width:1024.000000

which is what I expect. I'm surprise to have the appropriate size only in the viewDidAppear, please can you explain or is there something wrong in my storyboard?

Thanks,

Sébastien.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Frames are not correct in viewDidLoad.

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback. 
So when can I rely on the Frames size?

Comment: see @Tanner Nelson's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anything frame size dependent, I usually use

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
```

This will take into consideration Auto Rotate as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have overloaded the viewDidLayoutSubviews() and the frame size is correct.